# json_decode/encode on simplexmlelement adds arrays instead of empty strings

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, json

when loading an xml document and converting to an array using

```
json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), 1);
```

All empty xml nodes (`<node />`) are converted to array() I would like them to be an empty string instead.  Do I need to go through all elements and replace each empty node with something else?

I am loading the xml document with `$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($this->feed_uri, LIBXML_NOBLANKS | LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG , true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not accomplish that automatically. So you would need to replace empty arrays with empty strings after the conversion.

By the way, `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` makes no sense here:

> This option is currently just available in the DOMDocument::save and DOMDocument::saveXML functions.
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

Comment: bleh, that sucks.  the `libxml_noemptytag` was a last ditch effort I did read the docs but figured, just in case I'd try it, and thought maybe it may spark some creativity in someone.